# Importing articles with special characters

Tags: articles, import, character-encoding

I have to import some articles in my org that contain special characters, such as: `à,è,ì,ò,ù...` But when the import process ends, special characters aren't correctly displayed. I did a massive substitution with html code (`e.g. à --> &agrave;`) but it doesn't work, text still contains `&agrave;` instead of `à`.
I imported them with the standard salesforce tool, reachable from "Data Management -> Import articles" and in the .properties file I setted

```
CSVEncoding=UTF8
RTAEncoding=UTF8
DefaultHTMLEncoding=UTF8
CSVSeparator=;
#DateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd
```

Have you have any idea on how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you importing the articles? And where to? In general, import/export tools usually give you the option to select the text encoding when you upload something. If you have the option, you should look for UTF-8.

Comment: I imported them with the standard salesforce tool, reachable from "Data Management -> Import articles" and in the .properties file I setted `CSVEncoding=UTF8
RTAEncoding=UTF8
DefaultHTMLEncoding=UTF8`

Comment: The encoding for UTF-8 has the "-" character between "UTF" and "8". It should be `CSVEncoding=UTF-8`, for example. Can you try that?

Comment: No, it doesn't work :( Anyway thank you for you help :)

Comment: That's weird, because this help article says that. [https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_article_importer_03parameters.htm&language=en_US] - Are you sure your .csv files are encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, it was. It doesn't work.

Comment: Try this configuration: `CSVEncoding=UTF8
        DefaultHTMLEncoding=UTF-8
        RTAEncoding=UTF-8
        CSVSeparator=,
        #DateFormat=dd-MM-yyyy`